# ActiveAdmin custom values entered into form fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have an ActiveAdmin project in Rails 4. For some reason when I use the `:value => some_value` for a field nothing changes. It just shows up as an empty text field.

Here's an example of my form:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Template Details" do
  f.input :inventory_type, :value => "test"
  f.input :body_type
  f.input :section
  f.input :formula
  f.input :trait
end
f.actions
```

The inventory_type field is blank when it renders. I've tried all the other fields with similar results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this: `:input_html => {:value => "test"}`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Is there a way to do this for an input field that is a drop down selection?

Comment: Nevermind. Got it. I used `selected: item_to_select`