# ActiveAdmin get value from form text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activeadmin

I'm new in `Ruby` and make some simple admin using `ActiveAdmin`.
I have a model `Question` which I want to create, fill and store to database, it has an attribute `themes` (array of `Theme` models). When user creates a new record he doesn't enter themes manually but provide some string and system will automatically parse it and find or create themes. So I have code like that:

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs "Questions Details" do
      f.input :question, as: :string
      f.input :autocomplete_themes, hint: "You should enter here multiple themes,
      divide them with `,` or `;`"
    end
    f.actions
end
```

It creates a new field `autocomplete_themes` for entering string and it doesnt' exist in model `Question`. So what I want - is to get `autocomplete_themes` value like string and then use `split()` and my custom logic - but it gives an error.

```
before_create do |question|
    array = []
    puts "******"
    puts :autocomplete_themes.text
    themeTitles = :autocomplete_themes.split(",") #split(/,|;/)
    for title in themeTitles do
      theme = Theme.find_by(title: title)
      theme = Theme.create(title: title) unless theme
      array << theme
    end
    question.themes = array
end
```

**Question:** how can I get `autocomplete_themes` value as string? Thx!

**Update:** as I understood [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24209661/activeadmin-custom-values-entered-into-form-fields) - it looks like the similiar case, but there was problem with setting default value to custom field, but I need to get its value from code.

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify the error you were getting, but based on the information you gave, you don't need `autocomplete_themes` to be a real database-backed attribute of the `Question` model, but rather you only need the information temporarily so that your `before_create` filter can use it to execute the appropriate logic.

Therefore, you could make `autocomplete_themes` a "virtual attribute" that is like a traditional member variable of an instance of `Question`.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_writter :autocomplete_themes
attr_reader :autocomplete_themes

...other code
end
```

This will allow you to do things like:

```
@question.autocomplete_themes = "1,2,3"
themes_text = @question.auto_complete_themes
```

And best of all, ActiveAdmin supports having form inputs assign to virtual attributes. So you can keep your form like this:

```
form do |f|
f.inputs "Questions Details" do
  f.input :question, as: :string
  f.input :autocomplete_themes, hint: "You should enter here multiple themes,
  divide them with `,` or `;`"
end
f.actions
end
```

And your `before_filter` would look like this:

```
before_create do |question|
  array = []
  themeTitles = question.autocomplete_themes.split(",") #split(/,|;/)
  for title in themeTitles do
    theme = Theme.find_by(title: title)
    theme = Theme.create(title: title) unless theme
    array << theme
  end
  question.themes = array
end
```